How can i implement SNAP BI For BRI Virtual Account Online
i have project to integrate a laravel app for selling concert ticket. And i was told to add BRI API as one of the payment method. Since there is a new regulation to implement a new standard using SNAP BI. I dont have any knowledge about that. The product that i want to implement is their Briva Online. Which actually, i need to make service in my app for the BRI to hit. I dont really understand, since their documentation is not very explaining anything. If you want to share a litle bit experience how to do it. I'd be so thankfull... Thank you..
